# D365 v9 upgrade causing issues

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

yesterday we upgraded our d365 v8.x to v9.x, after that all of our web APIs calls failing.

it's throwing the following error.

A resource with type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.incident' was found, but it is not assignable to the expected type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.customentity'. The type specified in the resource must be equal to either the expected type or a derived type.

I am using d365 web API with OData and this error is coming when we are trying to execute fetchxml using webapi.

Comment: It might help to post an example of a call that's failing.

Comment: Sure I will update my question shortly

Comment: Odd. I'm not aware of any breaking change in the WebAPI behavior that would warrant this. It looks like you're attempting to populate an EntityReference with a reference to the wrong entity (and this has never worked). We need to see the details of the call in code to provide any kind of proper answer.

Comment: Alex, you are right I changed my API calls and it's started working but I have the same question why this worked in v8.2

Comment: @ManishTiwari Just a doubt, you sure in 8.2 You used WebAPI and not 2011 Endpoint which includes, XRMServiceToolKit, XrmSvcToolkit, SDK.REST,SDK.JQUERY and so on..

Because we moved few of organization from 8.2 to 9.0 and None had this issue with WebAPI calls.

Comment: @AnkUser I can confirm that some of modules of our app using odata and other using soap endpoint. We used soap endpoint (sdk) because of some limitations in odata .